# Is there a UAV that can carry 100kg at 350km/hr?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I've been searching for a Fixed Wing UAV or UAS that can do this:

Carry payload up to 100kg

Cruise at 350km/hr

Anyone know any that can do this?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect OleDahle is correct that civilian drones with these specs don't exist (350km/h is really fast...), but there are some which come close.  For instance, there is [the V100](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/1000km-range-Large-professional-100kg-payload_1600152568969.html?) on alibaba which is supposed to have a maximum payload of 100kg and max speed of 190km/h (it's unclear if those are mutually exclusive maximums).  It's still well under your speed specs, but depending why exactly you need that speed it might do the job.

The reason I'm making this a full answer is to point out several issues that you should be aware of:

- Even if you do find such a drone, it will be insanely expensive (the one I linked to costs quarter to half a million USD)
- Such a drone will almost certainly be special order, so you'll have to talk exact specs with your supplier
- You're going to have to take a really serious look into the local laws; it already takes a license for small drones in a lot of places, but something that massive is almost certainly going to be subject to furthur restrictions.   As long as you're bailing out half a million I would strongly recommend seeking professional legal assistance.

Comment: To add a bit of perspective, OP needs something the size of a hang glider or ultralight to carry 100kg. However their max speed is around 100km/h. 350km/h is about the top speed of the fastest, most powerful motorbikes or supercars. It's much faster than a typical light aircraft. The FAA has a class of 'high performance' aircraft with 200hp that can go this fast, and they cost about a million dollars.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any civilian drones that can do this, but large military UAVs have these capabilities:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAVs_in_the_U.S._military#List_of_U.S._military_UAVs